# Access fragment variable from adapter

Tags: android, adapter

I have a variable (int variable) in a fragment, I want to access it from adapter(possibly base adapter) set to one of the view( may be list view) of that fragment. How to best access that variable, without making to static.

Comment: Something like `public int getVariable();` ?

Comment: @TimCastelijns: You mean a getVariable() method in respective fragment class? If yes how to access that method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store a reference to the parent fragment in the adapter. Set it, for example, in the adapter's constructor.

```
public MyAdapter (MyFragment fragment) {
    this.fragment = fragment;
}

...
```

Then later access it in the adapter like this:

```
int var = fragment.getVariable();
```

In the fragment make a public method called `getVariable()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually i am already passing Activity context as one of the parameter to adpater's constructor. Is it possible to use it in anyway?

Comment: Yes. Usually my fragments are responsible for constructing the adapters. So when I construct an adapter, I just pass a reference to myself. Like this (in the fragment code): 

`MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), MyFragment.this);`

Then you have a references to the fragment in the adapter that you can use. Your activity context reference is untouched/not related.

Comment: Ok, only activity's context will not help? Is there any way to access the fragment's content using activities context?

Comment: Sure it's possible, but then you will need to pass the reference to your fragment through your activity to your adapter. You will need more code in your activity class (some method like `getFragment()`), without seeing it it's not possible to go into more detail.

Comment: do you feel its good idea to pass the entire fragment's instance to access just a int value?

Comment: Yes, why not, it's just a reference to an object, the same as passing the context in just to access...whatever you access via the context :)

Comment: I think if you just need to pass an int then pass in bundles using newInstance()